# How to configure APscheduler to use it with django_tenants

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, apscheduler

I am using django and django rest framework with multi teancy system.
For multitenancy I am using django_tenants package,

If I add "apscheduler" to TENANT_APPS and run migrate_schemas command I get this error

> Error getting due jobs from job store 'default': relation "rest_apscheduler_djangojob" does not exist
> LINE 1: ...d", "rest_apscheduler_djangojob"."job_state" FROM "rest_apsc...